# Transforming JavaScript Array into Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a strange requirement to transpose or transform a valid javascript array into another javascript object.

I am getting a server response in this format

```
{
"buyerPrimary.firstName":["The buyer primary.first name field is required."],
"buyerPrimary.lastName":["The buyer primary.last name field is required."]
}
```

I would like this array to be changed to this format.

```
{
    "buyerPrimary":{
        "firstName":["The buyer primary.first name field is required."],
        "lastName":["The buyer primary.last name field is required."]
    }
}
```

Still struggling in JavaScript and after hours of searching and trying, I have been unsuccessful. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Your object isn't a array. An array is defined by `[...]`. An object is defined by `{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an object, not an array.

You can use [*Object.keys*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.2.3.14) to get an array of the own property names of the object, then iterate over that using [*reduce*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4.4.21) to create the new object. The code below should be sufficiently commented, ask questions if not.

```js
    var data = {
      "buyerPrimary.firstName":["The buyer primary.first name field is required."],
      "buyerPrimary.lastName":["The buyer primary.last name field is required."]
    }
    
    var res = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (obj, key, idx) {

      // Split the key into the property names
      var props = key.split('.');

      // If the accumulator object doesn't have a suitable property already,
      // create it
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(props[0])) {
        obj[props[0]] = {};
      }

      // Add the property and value
      obj[props[0]][props[1]] = data[key];

      // Return the accumulator object to keep collecting properties
      return obj;

    // Initialise with an empty object as the accumulator
    }, {});
    
    // Display the result
    document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the operator `[...]` to get an object property.

```
var sourceObject = {
  "buyerPrimary.firstName":["The buyer primary.first name field is required."],
  "buyerPrimary.lastName":["The buyer primary.last name field is required."]
};
var destinationObject = {
  "buyerPrimary":{
    "firstName":sourceObject["buyerPrimary.firstName"],
    "lastName":sourceObject["buyerPrimary.lastName"]
  }
};
```